# Propper way to monitor SQL Server mirror status from service or job?

Tags: sql-server-2008, mirroring

We have a production DB which is in a mirror configuration. It is in `synchronous high safety with automatic failover` configuration. Right now we monitor it using windows service which pings it. Is there a better way to monitor mirror state using job or script?

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [Monitoring Database Mirroring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190030(v=sql.100).aspx) MSDN

You can monitor a mirrored database during a mirroring session to verify whether and how well data is flowing. To set up and manage monitoring for one or more of the mirrored databases on a server instance, you can use either Database Mirroring Monitor or the `sp_dbmmonitor` system stored procedures.

> A database mirroring monitoring job, Database Mirroring Monitor Job,
>   operates in the background, independently of Database Mirroring
>   Monitor. SQL Server Agent calls Database Mirroring Monitor Job at
>   regular intervals, the default is once a minute, and the job calls a
>   stored procedure that updates mirroring status. If you use SQL Server
>   Management Studio to start a mirroring session, Database Mirroring
>   Monitor Job is created automatically.

Also, if you want you can use the sys.database_mirroring view. You can query this Catalog View and raise an email alert for each mirrored database that we find in an abnormal state using below script as explained [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1859/monitoring-sql-server-database-mirroring-with-email-alerts/)

```
DECLARE @state VARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @DbMirrored INT
DECLARE @DbId INT
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @databases TABLE (DBid INT, mirroring_state_desc VARCHAR(30))

-- get status for mirrored databases
INSERT @databases
SELECT database_id, mirroring_state_desc
FROM sys.database_mirroring
WHERE mirroring_role_desc IN ('PRINCIPAL','MIRROR')
AND mirroring_state_desc NOT IN ('SYNCHRONIZED','SYNCHRONIZING')

-- iterate through mirrored databases and send email alert
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 DBid FROM @databases WHERE mirroring_state_desc IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
SELECT TOP 1 @DbId = DBid, @State = mirroring_state_desc
FROM @databases
SET @string = 'Host: '+@@servername+'.'+CAST(DB_NAME(@DbId) AS VARCHAR)+ ' - DB Mirroring is '+@state +' - notify DBA'
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 'valid_mail_profile', 'DBA@mssqltips.com', @body = @string, @subject = @string
DELETE FROM @databases WHERE DBid = @DbId
END

--also alert if there is no mirroring just in case there should be mirroring :)
SELECT @DbMirrored = COUNT(*)
FROM sys.database_mirroring
WHERE mirroring_state IS NOT NULL
IF @DbMirrored = 0
BEGIN
SET @string = 'Host: '+@@servername+' - No databases are mirrored on this server - notify DBA'
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 'valid_mail_profile', 'DBA@mssqltips.com', @body = @string, @subject = @string
END
```